# IPython.core.display not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, ipython

I have been attempting to work through Harvard's introductory data science course for Python and on one of the labs, I have run across an output problem.

I am using Spyder with the anaconda launcher and using Python 2.7. This is the code I am working with:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
import requests
import bs4

req = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_University")
page = req.text 

## req.text gives us the HTML code for the page 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')


## List comprehensions

[t["class"] for t in soup.find_all("table") if t.get("class")]


my_list = []
for t in soup.find_all("table"):
    if t.get("class"):
        my_list.append(t['class'])

table_html = str(soup.find("table", "wikitable"))

test = HTML(table_html)
```

The test should produce something like this: [image: What it should look like]

Instead I am just getting this in the console:

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

Is it the fact that I am using python 2.7 or am I missing something more?

Comment: Which console? If you are using a simple *terminal* with `ipython` then that kind of output isn't possible. You need to use the `qtconsole` or `notebook` frontend (which may be included in spyder but I'm not sure). Try to open the `qtconsole` outside Spyder and see if you get the desired output. If yes you have to make sure that Spyder indeed supports it and if so if there is some setting that is disabling it.

Comment: @Bakuriu thank you very much. They notebook work around was perfect. Looks like I will be using jupyter a lot more often now.